# Why OpenVPN Connection Reset automatically?

Tags: server, remote-server, data-transfer, openvpn

I am using OpenVPN for the data integration. but OpenVPN disconnect automatically after sometime.

Thanks
Amandeep

Answer (score 0):

Can you please add the following line in config file?

reneg-sec 0